# does Chrome Remote Desktop support Curtain Mode?

Tags: linux, chrome, remote-desktop

I use Chrome Remote Desktop to access my work machine which runs Linux Mint.  It's frustrating that, instead of connecting to my existing desktop session (so I can pick up where I left off), it starts a new session upon connecting.

I found that I can modify `/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop` to force a connection to my existing session like so:

```
#Change FIRST_X_DISPLAY_NUMBER to this:
FIRST_X_DISPLAY_NUMBER = 0

#Comment out the following lines:
#while os.path.exists(X_LOCK_FILE_TEMPLATE % display);
#display += 1

#Modify the launch_session() method so it's as follows:
def launch_session(self, x_args):
self._init_child_env()
self._setup_pulseaudio()
self._setup_gnubby()
#self._launch_x_server(x_args)
#self._launch_x_session()
display = self.get_unused_display_number()
self.child_env["DISPLAY"] = ":%d" % display
```

This works, but with a major caveat which has prevented me from actually using it: my monitors at the office stay on and the machine is unlocked for anyone to access.

The page [Control use of Chrome Remote Desktop](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2799701?hl=en)  refers to a "Curtain Mode" which is exactly what I want:

> To enable Chrome Remote Desktop to prevent someone physically present at a host machine from seeing what a user is doing while a remote connection is in progress

However the provided instructions for enabling it are only for Windows and Mac with no mention of Linux.

Is it possible to enable curtain mode for Linux hosts?

Answer (score -1):

To have the CRD on its own virtual screen for each user, follow the steps here:
https://overbrace.com/bernardparent/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=1491

This is similar to curtain mode. When you reconnect, you'll see the same screen you had when disconnecting.

Comment: Hello. It would be great if you could [edit] your answer and explain the steps here, so that your answer remains useful in case the URL changes or the linked tutorial goes offline.

Comment: Thanks, but this is how CRD already was working for me out of the box.  I want basically the opposite -- I want CRD *not* on its own virtual screen.  I want it to take over the session that I started on the host, and blank the screens at the host.